# difference between ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), Script, Script) and Page.RegisterStartupScript(Script, Script);

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

What is the difference between

> ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), Script, Script)

and

> Page.RegisterStartupScript(Script, Script);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Page.RegisterStartupScript` is now **[obsolete](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.registerstartupscript.aspx)** and *should not be used*..!

Use **[ClientScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.registerstartupscript.aspx)** instead...

It provides the same abilities as the former...

Answer (score 1):

If you use reflector you can see that

```
Page.RegisterStartupScript(Script, Script);
```

is calling ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript with the following parameters:

```
EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Advanced), Obsolete("The recommended alternative is   ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Type type, string key, string script). http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=14202")]
public virtual void RegisterStartupScript(string key, string script)
{
     this.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), key, script, false);
}
```